# jquery ui droppable: most dropped on?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two droppables very close together, and a draggable can be dropped on both at the same time.  Is there a way to figure out which one it is dropped more on, defined by % overlap?

Thank you.

-Nick

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or some code? I am having trouble visualizing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the absolute position of both static elements (http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
2. Get the absolute position of the draggable element
3. Calculate the size of the overlap between the draggable element and each static element

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, since
1) I'm lazy and was hoping jquery ui had an automagical way of doing it
2) The drop function is called one after the other.  Is there a way to have one method called with a list of all that was dropped on?

Comment: Well, to answer 1 I don't know. You do however get the position of the element when drag ends. The rest I didn't understand. Can you clarify?